# Object Oriented Programming - Unclear why the IF statement in a method is not working

Tags: python, class, if-statement, methods

```
class PlugLead:

    def __init__(self, mapping):
        self.map1 = mapping[0]
        print(self.map1)
        self.map2 = mapping[1]
        print(self.map2)

    def encode(self, character):
        print(character)
        print(type(character))
        print(self.map1 == character)
        if self.map1 == character is True:
            return self.map2
        elif self.map2 == character is True:
            return self.map1
        else:
            return character


lead = PlugLead("zc")

lead.encode("z")
```

When I run the above code, I get the following. Something is bugging with the IF statement but I can't figure out what! Thank you

z

c

z

<class 'str'>

True

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Remove `is True` from the expressions in your `if` statements

Comment: you can remove is True

Answer (score 0):

The `is` operator is evaluated first, then `==`.

So this comparison:

```py
self.map1 == character is True
```

is effectively same as:

```py
self.map1 == (character is True)
```

which always return `False`.

You can skip the comparison with `True`:

```py
    if self.map1 == character:
        return self.map2
    elif self.map2 == character:
        return self.map1
    else:
        return character
```

By the way you are calling `lead.encode("z")` but you didn't tell python to print it so it wouldn't say anything about what `encode()` returns.